# Transfer a partial differential expression by substituting $u = xz$ and $v = yz$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

> Let $A = (\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}})^2 + (\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}})^2$. Transfer $A$ when considering $x$ as a function and $u = xz$ and $v = yz$ as independent variables.

It is an exercise practicing for my test that my teacher gave me. At first $z = z(x, y)$ and we must transfer to a new expression where $x=x(u, v)$ where $u, v$ are defined as above. At first I think that the problem is incorrect, but it's not. My teacher gave us something kind of clues but I can't do anything more: $u = xz$ and then derivative both sides in term of $u$, we get $1 = \frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{u}}.z + \frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{u}}.x$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Thank you Michael Albanese. It is an exercise practicing for my test that my teacher gave me. At first $z = z(x, y)$ and we must transfer to a new expression where $x=x(u, v)$ where $u, v$ are defined as above. At first I think that the problem is incorrect, but it's not. My teacher gave us something kind of clues but I can't do anything more: $u = xz$ and then derivative both sides in term of $u$, we get $1 = \frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{u}}.z + \frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{u}}.x$